# Is it possible to move a jquery draggable element with a click function and have it recognized by droppable?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a draggable element holding an transparent png to mask other images that are placed in droppable elements. Now I'm searching for another way to move the draggable element beside dragging it with the mouse.

I added up / down arrows and bound a click function to them which animated the draggable element to the next possible droppable element - animation works fine but the droppable element does not recognize the draggable element and my over & out functions don't work :(

how do i get the droppable element to recognize my draggable element when it isn't dragged but moved by the click function?

-> check it here: http://www.ifm-service.com/test/

when dragged masked image appears - if moved by clicking the links nothing happens!

Comment: post an example on jsfiddle.net.. will you ? Its really a pain to read this type of sentences. Posting code/example will make the question a lot more simpler

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options.  You could define your `over` and `out` functions as separate functions:

```
function overFunc){...}
function outFunc){...}

$(".droparea").droppable({  
   out: outFunc,
   over: overFunc
});
```

Then you can simply call those functions independently when needed.

The other option is to call the droppable functions like this (untested but I believe this is they syntax):

```
$("#droppable").droppable('option', 'out')()
```

It depends on your situation but you may have issues with context either way.  The first obviously has no context at all so you will want to call it with `.apply` in order to use `this`.  The 2nd may have the ability to use `this` to get the droppable but obviously has no access to what is being dropped if there are multiple droppables.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the problem is that when you set the handlers to the click function to `move up` and `move down`, you have to specify to hide the image and call the new image based on the current position of the mask.

You could have seperate functions defined that will handle out and over.

and bind the same function to click as well as drag handlers. To track the current position of the div have a variable that tells the current position, say

```
var position = 0;

function onOUT(direction){
   if(direction == "up")
     position--;
   else
     position++;
   //hide current image.
}
function onIN() {
   //display image at current position
}
```

Note : Make sure the `onOUT` and `onIN` functions are independent of the place from where it is called. 
( OR ) . `this` inside the function should not decide the postion or moving the element. If it decides then it will give an error, since `this` points to different objects when dragging and when using separate buttons.